# Pyramid authn and authz : strange behaviour of 'logout'

Tags: python, authentication, authorization, pyramid

The login worked well, my logout_view:

```
@view_config(route_name='logout')
def logout_view(request):
    headers = forget(request)
    raise HTTPFound(location='request.application_url',headers=headers)
```

The output I got:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
 (in template single.pt LINE 11: "<p tal:content="result.name"></p>")
```

It seems that,

1. the `forget` and `HTTPFound` were not called at all, since the browser stucks at "0.0.0.0:6543/logout, saying *Internal Server Error*.
2. the `logout_view` has nothing to do with the `single.pt` template, but it seems that the `single.pt` is rendered somewhere.

btw,`single.pt` template is only used in the flollowing `rst_view`, which is associated with `config.add_route('rst', '/{id}')`:

```
@view_config(route_name='rst', renderer='templates/single.pt',
             permission='edit',)
def rst_view(request):
    rstId=request.matchdict['id']
    rst=DBSession.query(Rst).get(rstId)
    return {
    'result':rst,
    'logged_in':authenticated_userid(request),
}
```

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your route ordering is messed up and `/{id}` is matching before `/logout`, effectively hiding it. Reverse your `add_route` calls to that logout is matched first.

Comment: Thanks Michael. It worked. I didn't take care of the pattern [[uniqueness,] order] .